# docker-ce : Depends: containerd.io (>= 1.4.1) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: docker, debian, containerd, docker-ce

I have an error when trying to install Docker on Debian 10 (Buster)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-ce : Depends: containerd.io (>= 1.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to install the last version of *containerd.io* on *download.docker.com.*

```
curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.4.3-1_amd64.deb
```

```
sudo apt install ./containerd.io_1.4.3-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because I applied Docker installation steps for Ubuntu on my Debian server.

To fix this:

- Clear the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`
- Try to install Docker CE again using official Docker [docs for Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)